# Is there a communication standard for IP cameras?

Tags: ip-camera

I am trying to chose an IP camera for outdoor surveillance, but I am not sure how I will be able to communicate with it. Afaik. these cameras have an IP address on the local network, which I can access to get the video stream. But what about the controlling part, like rotation, zoom, IR movement sensor, etc? Is there a communication standard for that, or should I try to find some kind of developer documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that ONVIF is the most prevalent communication standard by IP cameras. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ONVIF